# Nodejs client connection close safely

Tags: html, node.js, websocket

I am new to Nodejs and I am using nodejs websocket to try to communicate with a client application. What I need help is safely closing the client connection while not crashing my nodejs server. More specially check to see if there is a connection before the nodejs server sends back a message to the client.

Client app code

```
function tuneIn(){
    connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8001');
    connection.onmessage = function (event) { 
        document.getElementById('currentScore').innerHTML=event.data;
    };
}

tuneInButton.addEventListener('click', tuneIn);

function tuneOut(){
    connection.close();
}
tuneOutButton.addEventListener('click', tuneOut);
```

Node js code

```
var ws = require("nodejs-websocket");

var server = ws.createServer(function (conn) {

    console.log("New connection");
    var score = 0;
    setInterval(function(){ 
        conn.sendText(score.toString());
        score++; 
    }, 1000);


    conn.on("disconnect", function (code, reason) {
        console.log("Connection closed")
    })
}).listen(8001)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just stop the interval timer when the websocket disconnects?

```
const ws = require("nodejs-websocket");

const server = ws.createServer(function (conn) {

    console.log("New connection");
    let score = 0;
    let timer = setInterval(function(){ 
        conn.sendText(score.toString());
        score++; 
    }, 1000);


    conn.on("disconnect", function (code, reason) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        console.log("Connection closed")
    })
}).listen(8001)
```

Comment: @axesspwns - Did this answer your question? If so, you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. That will also earn you some reputation points here on stackoverflow for following the proper procedure. If this didn't answer your question, please comment about which part of your question you're still confused about.